# Changing the text of a button (from a child class) when a function is triggered in another child class. Kivy

Tags: python, oop, callback, kivy, ids

Here I have program that calculates profit based on expenses and revenue.

[image]

It works just fine as shown in the image. What I'm trying to do is change the text of buttons in the bottom most boxlayout every time the `calc()` function is triggered in the `MyGrid()` class. I tried to use id's but I'm doing it wrong. Also I tried using the `on_press` method in my .kv file but I actually want the `button.text` to change **EVERYTIME** the `calc()` is triggered irrespective of the button being pressed or not.
**NOTE:** only the `MyGrid()` class and MyScroll: is worth looking at everything else works as expected

```````
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp

Builder.load_file("sample1.kv")

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass
    
class HeaderBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (1,0.1)
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        self.headers = ["Name","Price","Quantity","Name","Price","Quantity"]
        for i in range(6):
            b = Button(text=str(self.headers[i]))
            self.add_widget(b)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 6
        self.textinputs=[0] #i put a 0 in that list so that my object indexing can start with 1

        #made a diff list full of indexes so i can use them in my calculating algo
        self.expense_price_index = [2,8,14,20,26,32,38,44,50,56] 
        self.expense_quantity_index = [3,9,15,21,27,33,39,45,51,57]
        self.revenue_price_index = [5,11,17,23,29,35,41,47,53,59]  
        self.revenue_quantity_index = [6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60]

        #initializing some values
        self.expense_total = 0
        self.revenue_total = 0
        self.profit = 0

        #making a grid full of textinputs and adding them to self.textinputs list 
        for i in range(60):
            b = TextInput(multiline=False,font_size=dp(20),size_hint=(1,None),height=50)
            b.bind(on_text_validate=self.calc) #binding a function to make my calculations
            self.textinputs.append(b)
            self.add_widget(b)            

    #FUNCTION THAT DOES THE CALCULATIONS
    def calc(self,ti_instance):
        default_quantity = 1
        self.expense_total = 0
        self.revenue_total = 0

        # CALCULATING EXPENSE TOTAL
        for i in self.expense_price_index:
            if self.textinputs[i].text == "":
                continue
            elif self.textinputs[i+1].text == "":
                self.expense_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * default_quantity
            else:
                self.expense_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * int(self.textinputs[i+1].text) 
        # CALCULATING REVENUE TOTAL
        for i in self.revenue_price_index:
            if self.textinputs[i].text == "":
                continue
            elif self.textinputs[i+1].text == "":
                self.revenue_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * default_quantity
            else:
                self.revenue_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * int(self.textinputs[i+1].text)            
     
        # CALCULATING PROFIT DOING BASIC ARITHMETIC  
        self.profit = str(self.revenue_total - self.expense_total)
        print("Profit: " + self.profit)            

class MyScroll(ScrollView):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()       ```

```#:import dt datetime.date
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp
#:set navbar_button_color (59/255, 68/255, 75/255, 1)


<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.1
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Home"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Daily"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Weekly"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Monthly" 
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Label:
            text: dt.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")
            size_hint: 0.5,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 59/255, 78/255, 85/255,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos    
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.15
        Button:
            text: "EXPENSES"            
        Button:
            text: "REVENUE"    
    HeaderBox:
    MyScroll:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        size_hint: 1,0.2       
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "Expense Total:"
                font_size: dp(20)
                on_press:
                    self.text: "Expense Total: " + str(my_grid.expense_total)
            Button:
                text: "Revenue Total:"
                font_size: dp(20)
                on_press:
                    self.text: "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)
        Button:
            text: "Profit:"
            font_size: dp(40)       
            on_press:
                self.text: "Profit: " + str(my_grid.profit)

                      
<MyScroll>:    
    my_grid: my_grid
    MyGrid:
        id: my_grid
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height```

 #for @ApuCoder
```Button:
       id: revenue_button
       text: "Revenue Total: " 
       font_size: dp(20)
       on_press:
          self.text = "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)```  
 ```class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        expense_button = ObjectProperty()``` 
  ```# CALCULATING PROFIT DOING BASIC ARITHMETIC  
        self.profit = str(self.revenue_total - self.expense_total)
        self.expense_button.text = "Expense Total: " + str(self.expense_total)  <-----
        print("Profit: " + self.profit)   ``````
```````

Answer (score 0):

You can access your `MyGrid` in `python` or `kvlang` by creating a reference. One of the few ways is simply using an `id`.

With this and other necessary modifications your full code in `kvlang` looks like,

```py
#:import dt datetime.date
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp
#:set navbar_button_color (59/255, 68/255, 75/255, 1)


<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.1
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Home"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Daily"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Weekly"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Monthly" 
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Label:
            text: dt.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")
            size_hint: 0.5,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 59/255, 78/255, 85/255,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos    
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.15
        Button:
            text: "EXPENSES"            
        Button:
            text: "REVENUE"    
    HeaderBox:
    MyScroll: # Add the grid directly here.
        MyGrid:
            id: my_grid
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        size_hint: 1,0.2       
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
#                text: "Expense Total:"
                text: "Expense Total: " + str(my_grid.expense_total)
                font_size: dp(20)
                on_press:
                    self.text = "Expense Total: " + str(my_grid.expense_total)
            Button:
#                text: "Revenue Total:"
                text: "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)
                font_size: dp(20)
                on_press:
                    self.text = "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)
        Button:
#            text: "Profit:"
            text: "Profit: " + str(my_grid.profit)
            font_size: dp(40)       
            on_press:
                self.text = "Profit: " + str(my_grid.profit)

                      
#<MyScroll>:    
#    my_grid: my_grid
#    MyGrid:
#        id: my_grid
#        size_hint: 1, None
#        height: self.minimum_height
```

Now create some properties for those attributes using `NumericProperty` in `python`.

Modified full code in `python`,

```py
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty



Builder.load_file("sample1.kv")



class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass
    
class HeaderBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (1,0.1)
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        self.headers = ["Name","Price","Quantity","Name","Price","Quantity"]
        for i in range(6):
            b = Button(text=str(self.headers[i]))
            self.add_widget(b)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    expense_total = NumericProperty(0)
    profit = NumericProperty(0)
    revenue_total = NumericProperty(0)
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 6
        self.textinputs=[0] #i put a 0 in that list so that my object indexing can start with 1

        #made a diff list full of indexes so i can use them in my calculating algo
        self.expense_price_index = [2,8,14,20,26,32,38,44,50,56] # range(2, 60, 6)
        self.expense_quantity_index = [3,9,15,21,27,33,39,45,51,57] # range(3, 60, 6) etc.
        self.revenue_price_index = [5,11,17,23,29,35,41,47,53,59]  
        self.revenue_quantity_index = [6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60]

        #initializing some values
#        self.expense_total = 0
#        self.revenue_total = 0
#        self.profit = 0

        #making a grid full of textinputs and adding them to self.textinputs list 
        for i in range(60):
            b = TextInput(multiline=False,font_size=dp(20),size_hint=(1,None),height=50)
            b.bind(on_text_validate=self.calc) # binding a function to make my calculations
#            b.bind(text=self.calc) # Bound to the property text.
            self.textinputs.append(b)
            self.add_widget(b)            

    #FUNCTION THAT DOES THE CALCULATIONS
    def calc(self,ti_instance):
#    def calc(self,ti_instance, text): # If bound to the property text.
        default_quantity = 1
        self.expense_total = 0
        self.revenue_total = 0

        # CALCULATING EXPENSE TOTAL
        for i in self.expense_price_index:
            if self.textinputs[i].text == "":
                continue
            elif self.textinputs[i+1].text == "":
                self.expense_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * default_quantity
            else:
                self.expense_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * int(self.textinputs[i+1].text) 
        # CALCULATING REVENUE TOTAL
        for i in self.revenue_price_index:
            if self.textinputs[i].text == "":
                continue
            elif self.textinputs[i+1].text == "":
                self.revenue_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * default_quantity
            else:
                self.revenue_total += int(self.textinputs[i].text) * int(self.textinputs[i+1].text)            
     
        # CALCULATING PROFIT DOING BASIC ARITHMETIC  
        self.profit = self.revenue_total - self.expense_total
        print("Profit: " + str(self.profit))

class MyScroll(ScrollView):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: okay the code is working perfectly fine with your modifications, the button.text does change when i click on the button but i want the button.text to change dynamically while i type data into the grid. i thought of giving the button id's and cahnges their respective id.text property in my calc() method but i can't access those buttons coz they don't belong in the MyGrid() class.

Comment: to make myself clear i have added the code changes i did at the very bottom of my code

Comment: *'but i want the button.text to change dynamically while i type data into the grid...'* For that I already added (binding to`text`) to the code. Just uncomment those lines and comment out others.

Comment: yes i did exactly that but its still not changing dynamically. According to the mods the calc() method gets triggered anytime something is typed and it does update all the values of those variables but there's no line of code to change the displayed text of the button still. i was expecting something like expense_button.text = "Expense total:" + str(self.expense_total)